# Refresh CSRF Token in all forms automatically

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, csrf, csrf-protection

I've noticed that when I open my app and don't do anything for like 2 hours the csrf token expires. Since the session is still valid I'd like to know if there's a best pratice to automatically refresh all csrf tokens of my forms.

I found the following for handling these exceptions https://gist.github.com/jrmadsen67/bd0f9ad0ef1ed6bb594e

However, I'd love to skip that redirect.

Is there anything wrong with creating a script that calls the backend every hour or so to fetch a new token and then refresh all _token inputs using jquery?

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    // add ajax stuff here
    $('input[name=_token]').val(new_token);
}, 1800000);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check out [Laravel Caffeine](https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine).

It does exactly what you're after, by keeping forms alive and able to be submitted after being left to sit for extended periods of time.